# Python : how to parse string pieces got from a table

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I don't know how to proceed to get pieces of string I got from a table.

Here is the html td:

```
<tr>
<td class="">1</td><td><a 
 href="http://www.canalturf.com/courses_fiche_cheval.php? 
 idcheval=227579&amp;idcourse=173937" target="_blank" title="La fiche du 
 cheval EQUEMAUVILLE "><strong>EQUEMAUVILLE  (H4)</strong><br> 
 <small>4s3s1s6s5h(17)2h2h3h7h</small><div class="pedigree hidden"> 
 <small>SAINT DES SAINTS - MISS ACADEMY</small></div></a>
</td>
<td><div style="width:30px; height:35px; overflow:hidden"><img 
 src="http://www.canalturf.com/interface/casaques/173937.png" 
 style="width:100%; position:relative; top:0px"></div>
</td>
<td><a href="http://www.canalturf.com/courses_fiche_jockey.php? 
idjockey=3080&amp;date=2018-08-04" target="_blank" title="La fiche du 
 jockey/driver D. GALLON"><strong>D. GALLON</strong></a><br><a 
 href="http://www.canalturf.com/courses_fiche_entraineur.php? 
 identraineur=171&amp;date=2018-08-04" target="_blank" title="La fiche de 
 l'entraineur F.NICOLLE"><small>F.NICOLLE</small></a></td><td>71.0 kg
</td>
<td 
 class="text-center bord-lft">9</td><td class="text-center bord-lft text- 
 success">-40%</td><td class="text-center bord-lft"><a 
 href="https://eule1.pmu.fr/dynclick/pmu/?eaf- 
 publisher=ACQHIPPIQUECANALTURF_CANALTURF&amp;eaf- 
 name=ACQHIPPIQUECANALTURF_CANALTURF_2010_WEB_AFF_FILROUGE&amp;eaf- 
 creative=ACQ_H_DESKTOP_ETIRELIRE_BANNIERE&amp;eaf- 
 creativetype=BANNIERE&amp;eseg-name=ia-affilie&amp;eseg- 
 item=a_Canalturfb_TEXTEc_aid&amp; 
 mediaplan=2010_WEB_AFF_FILROUGE&amp;eurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.Fturf%2Fouver 
 ture-compte%2Fstandard%2F%3F2%26hippique- 
 tirelire%26ns_mchannel%3DAFF%26ns_source%3DACQHIPPIQUECANALTURF_CANALTURF" 
 target="_blank" onclick="handleOutboundLinkClicks('PMUClic', 'pmuCote', 
 '1');">5.4</a></td><td class="text-center bord-lft"><a 
 href="https://www.zeturf.fr/fr/inscription?
 pid=88&amp;affutm_source=Affiliation&amp;utm_medium=Canalturf&amp;u 
 tm_campaign=ZT_FR_Affiliation_Filrouge_Logo_2018" target="_blank" 
 onclick="handleOutboundLinkClicks('ZTClic', 'ztCote', '1');">5</a></td><td 
 class="text-center bord-lft"><a 
 href="http://wlbetclicfr.adsrv.eacdn.com/C.ashx? 
 btag=a_920b_260c_&amp;affid=590&amp;siteid=920&amp;adid=260&amp;c=turf" 
 target="_blank" onclick="handleOutboundLinkClicks('BTClic', 'btCote', 
 '1');">-- 
 </a>
</td>
<td class="text-center bord-lft"><a 
 href="http://media.unibet.fr/redirect.aspx? 
 pid=32884&amp;bid=2223" target="_blank" 
 onclick="handleOutboundLinkClicks('UNClic', 'unCote', '1');">4.8</a>
</td>
```

Here is the value I get :

```
1,EQUEMAUVILLE  (H4)4s3s1s6s5h(17)2h2h3h7hSAINT DES SAINTS - MISS ACADEMY,AP,F. OUVRIEJ. FOIN,2700m,47,+28%,60,67.6,67.78,--
```

Here is what i looking for :

```
1,EQUEMAUVILLE,H4,4s3s1s6s5h(17)2h2h3h7h,SAINT DES SAINTS,MISS ACADEMY,AP,F. OUVRIEJ. FOIN,2700m,47,+28%,60,67.6,67.78,--
```

I get this value like this :

```
table = soup2.find("table", attrs={"id":"TablePartants"})

headers = [th.text for th in table.select("tr th")]

with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
  wr = csv.writer(f,lineterminator = '\n')
  #wr.writerow(headers)
  wr.writerows([[td.text for td in row.find_all("td")] for row in table.select("tr")])
```

Must I use regex ? Or can I parse them before with special html tag? 
I am little confused.

If anyone can help me I will be very grateful. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You may be a little confused but can at least read the HTML that you are trying to parse. I cannot, so I cannot help your. You should show the HTML for a full row if you want help in parsing it...

Comment: I edited the post and add the html <td>. Sorry.

Comment: The `<td>` block that you have shown is not the one that could lead to the data that you want. And you have only shown one `<td>` block, when a `<tr>` could contain different ones... Anyway, as one single `<td>` block seems to contain more that one field, you will have to use BeautifulSoup to individually find the fields.

Comment: The HTML you added does not line up with the values you say you are trying to extract, so it is very difficult to advise further. Either post the matching HTML fragment, or change the desired output to match the HTML you added.

Comment: Sorry for delay, my internet connection is bad ><. I edited the post with informations you need. The html code match with what I would like. Thanks for your help.